# p:calendar component does not submit selected value, throws throws NullPointerException

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow

I'm using spring webflow and primefaces for my application UI and I have an issue with the `<p:calendar />` component.

Before the application page is displayed I have initialized some items and put them in conversationscope using current request context.

```
//WEBFLOW ACTION
<action-state id="state_init">
    <evaluate expression="myController.initializeParams()" /> 
    <transition on="create" to="create_Action"/>
</action-state>
```

Controller method.....

```
public void initializeParams() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
    Date listFromDate = null;
    Date listUptoDate = null;
    String searchParam = "";  

    context.getConversationScope().asMap().put("listFromDate", listFromDate );
    context.getConversationScope().asMap().put("listUptoDate", listUptoDate );
    context.getConversationScope().asMap().put("searchParam", searchParam);
    context.getConversationScope().asMap().put("selectedBudget", null);  
    context.getConversationScope().asMap().put("costcenter", null);
}
```

Xhtml code .....

```
<p:calendar value="${listFromDate}" pattern="dd/MMM/yyyy" showOn="button" size="11" style="float: right" 
            autocomplete="false" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true"/>
<p:autoComplete id="branchCombo" value="#{costcenter}"
                                                completeMethod="${costcenterController.completeActiveCenters}"
                                                var="cc" itemLabel="#{cc.description}"
                                                itemValue="#{cc}" converter="${costcenterConverter}" 
                                                dropdown="true" forceSelection="true" scrollHeight="100"/>
```

If I select a date on the calendar and submit the form I get bellow **NullPointerException** error, but if I submit the form without selecting the calendar (I select only autocomplete) I don't get any error

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Servlet Dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet Servlet Dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.webflow.expression.el.ScopeSearchingELResolver.getType(ScopeSearchingELResolver.java:79)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getType(CompositeELResolver.java:327)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:215)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:242)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getType(AstIdentifier.java:83)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:201)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
at org.primefaces.component.calendar.CalendarRenderer.getConvertedValue(CalendarRenderer.java:271)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)
at org.primefaces.component.calendar.Calendar.validate(Calendar.java:578)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.invokePhase(FlowLifecycle.java:91)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowLifecycle.execute(FlowLifecycle.java:69)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.processUserEvent(JsfView.java:113)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:225)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:195)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:168)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:254)
at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:134)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

> Primefaces 6.1 Spring Webflow 2.4.7 Mojarra 2.2.12

Comment: So if you replace the `p:calendar` with an `h:inputText` you don't get the npe? And I see you use a composite component. What if you put all code directly in the page? see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and [mcve]

Comment: What is this craziness? `context.getConversationScope().asMap().put("listFromDate", listFromDate);` I'm not familiar with  what's normal within "Spring", but that approach surely doesn't seem to be typed and writable at all. Try using normal managed beans instead. Or, if you absolutely need to, just do something like `context.getConversationScope().asMap().put("bean", this);` and then `value="#{bean.listFromDate}`. That would make it at least to be properly typed and writable.